# Merge multiple worksbooks but only specific sheet from each one

Tags: vba

Here's my struggle.. I found this macro, which I'm trying to modify so I only get select worksheet copied (in my case, I want the sheet called "Indexable"). I'm clueless how to get that... please help

```vb
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
    Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook
 
    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)
 
    If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then
 
        If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0
 
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook
 
            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1
 
                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)
 
                For Each wks In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                    countSheets = countSheets + 1
                    wks.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
                Next
 
                wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
 
            Next
 
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 
            MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If
 
    Else
        MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each wks In wbkSrcBook.Sheets`... that's the loop you want to get rid of.

Comment: Ok, but what do I replace it with? I'm completely new to VBS. I basically need only one sheet (named Indexable) out of a total of 8 different tabs copied.

Comment: `wbkSrcBook.Worksheets("Indexable").Copy After:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)`.

Comment: I'm still confused and can't get it to work. If I remove the entire block "For each wks.." until Next and then copy in your block and Next, I get an error. Please help this simpleton. :-)

Comment: There shouldn't be a `Next`. Remove `For Each wks In wbkSrcBook.Sheets`, `wks.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)`, and `Next`, and insert the line of code above.

Comment: Awesome! Really appreciate your help